# Differences between [in, out] and [out, retval] in COM IDL definitions

Tags: com, idl, notation

In some of the IDL I work with I have noticed that there are 2 conventions for marking return values in methods - `[in, out]` and `[out, retval]`.

It appears that `[in, out]` is used when there are multiple return values, for example:

```
HRESULT MyMethod(
    [in] long InputParam, 
    [in, out] long* OutputParam1, 
    [in, out] long* OutputParam2
);
```

It appears that `[out, retval]` is used when there is only a single return value, for example:

```
HRESULT MyMethod2(
    [in] long InputParam, 
    [out, retval] long* OutputParam1
);
```

Is this a COM IDL convention or just a convention in the code I am working with?

Is there a functional difference in the code that will be generated from the 2 notations, or are they completely interchangeable?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`[in, out]` means that a valid value is passed when the method is called and a valid value is there (where the pointer points) when the method returns success. `[out]` means that the value pointed to can be whatever when the method is called but it will be valid when the method returns success. Both `[out]` and `[in, out]` parameters must be pointers - their values are unchanged and valid and the validity requirements only apply to the variables they point to.

`[out, retval]` is a syntactic sugar to indicate that when creating a Native COM Support wrapper this very parameter should be converted to a return value. For example

```
HRESULT MyMethod( [out] long* OutParam1, [out, retval] long* OutParam2 );
```

becomes

```
long IWrappedInterface::MyMethod( long* OutParam1 );
```

If you don't mark it `[retval]` the wrapper will contain a method with the original signature:

```
HRESULT IWrappedInterface::MyMethod( long* OutParam1, long* OutParam2 );
```

Only the last one `[out]` parameter can be marked as `[out, retval]`. `[in, out]` parameters can't be marked as `[retval]`.

Comment: I'd like to add that `[in,out]` may not be handled correctly by all languages (more specifically, old-school Visual Basic, not sure about .NET).

Comment: I'm wondering if [out, retval] is against best practice to define COM interfaces since there is no way to get error code (HRESULT) if execution fails?

Comment: @dave: If execution fails an appropriate HRESULT is returned. If you're calling the method via "raw interface" the signature is such that `HRESULT` is returned and you can check it. If you're calling a Native COM Support wrapper which returns something other than `HRESULT` then this wrapper will have a check inside it and call `_com_issue_error()` which will be mapped onto some function that throws an exception. So this isn't a problem.

Comment: Elaborating on @KimGräsman's comment: Visual Basic ("classic"?) doesn't support `[in, out]`. An `[in, out]` parameter will be handled by Visual Basic code implementing the method as if it were `[out]`. Which means that whatever value the parameter points at when the method is called will be discarded and overwritten without checking, possibly causing a leak. Sometimes it doesn't matter (e.g. parameter points at local int), and sometimes it does (parameter pointing at a BSTR)

Answer (score 0):

Another difference is how this will show up in a PIA in .NET code.

[out, ret] will show up as a return value in .NET.

[out] will show up an argument on the method in .NET.